# could not remove the error message on validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was testing a learning Form validation, I could not remove error text.
The HTML Code was like this

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Requester<span class="required text-danger">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <small style="display: none"></small>
        </div>
```

**With Jquery to validate**

```
var errors = 0;
var submitted = false;

var addError = function (element, siblings, errorMessage) {
    if (element.style.display == "none") {
        console.log(element);
        return;
    }

    errors++;
    $(element).addClass("text-error")

    siblings.each(function (index, sib) {
        if (sib.tagName == "SMALL") {
            sib.innerText = errorMessage
            $(sib).addClass("text-danger");
            $(sib).addClass("font-weight-bold");
            $(sib).show();
        }
    })
};
```

**And a function to remove the errors**

```
var removeError = function (element, siblings) {
    $(element).removeClass("text-error");

    siblings.each(function (index, sib) {
        if (sib.tagName == "SMALL") {
            sib.innerText = ""
            $(sib).removeClass("text-danger");
            $(sib).removeClass("font-weight-bold");
            $(sib).hide();
        }
    })
};
```

When I removed the  `<small style="display: none"></small>` and `<span class="required text-danger">*</span>` it did not make any change it still shows RED error box and Sweetalert.js message,
is there anyway I can make it work, how can I remove the error for non required fields.
**Ref code pen link :https://codepen.io/dunya/pen/KYdQPd**
Many thanks

Comment: What do you want exactly ?

Comment: I will have more fields, the code should not validate if the field is not required but I could not make it work, it is acting as required even I removed SPANs. So this should be running without error as it is not required.